# Is this group non-abelian

Tags: group-theory

Is the group $G = \langle a,b \mid  a^2b^2ab^{-1}, a^3b^4a^{-2}b^{-3}\rangle$ non-abelian? If $G$ is abelian then $G = G_{ab} = \mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus, to show that $G$ is non-abelian it is necessary and sufficient to prove that $a^2 \neq 1$ or $a\neq b$.

Comment: Why are you considering this presentation in particular? It is probably true to say that most investigations of difficult individual group presentations are done with computer assistance these days (for the same reason that you would use a calculator for a complicated arithmetical calculation). Is there any particular reason why it would be desirable to have a hand proof in this case?

Comment: No particular reason, just amazed how helpless we are before the face of group theory!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that $G \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2$. You can plug in your relations or equivalently
$$a^2 b^2a = b; a^3b^4 = b^3 a^2$$
into Kyle Miller's implementation of the Todd-Coxeter algorithm found here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~kmill/tools/tc.html.

Wikipedia has a decent article about the algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd%E2%80%93Coxeter_algorithm.

Comment: [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) also computes it in no time, I assume also using Todd-Coxeter.

Comment: What if I do not believe to computer? At least how hard is it to deduce $a^2$ from the given words?

Comment: Perhaps you can compute using the algorithm by hand or have a computer output its computation.